# How to push my commits from a new local branch to the remote branch in Git

Tags: git

The remote repo has master and staging branches, and I am only supposed to work in staging. The first thing I did was clone the repo down to my local computer. Then I used `git checkout -b form origin/staging` to create and checkout a new local branch and have that track the `origin/staging` remote.

Now I have several commits and am ready to push that to the staging.  How do I do that? Can I simply type git push?  If I did that, will it just push my commits into the staging branch on the remote or will it create a new branch called forms into the repo which is not what I want.

Comment: You should probably first `git pull --rebase` to get the newest changes to `origin/staging` and `push` afterwards.

Comment: @Micha - right already used git fetch prior...but my concern is still if the commit will go into proper staging branch and not create a new branch...Also I don't want to inadvertently push to the master...

Comment: They will go into the correct branch. But you can always just create two repositories on your machine and try out the commands you are unsure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
git push repo_name from:to
```

So for your case:

```
git push origin form:staging
```

You could need to update your code before:

```
# will update merging
git pull
```

Or:

```
# will update rebasing
git pull --rebase
```

For a difference between rebase and merge check [this](http://gitguru.com/2009/02/03/rebase-v-merge-in-git/).

You could also pass your changes in `form` to `staging` local branches:

```
# to change local branch
git checkout staging

# to get changes from form branch in staging branch
git merge form

# to push corresponding branch
git push
```

This way you won't have to give a refspec `from:to`

Comment: ok I guess "origin" is the word that scares me.  In my local I have master and a branch called "form" as I am working with html forms.  I was just afraid "origin" would mean master and I would be pushing master to the staging when I wanted "form" to be pushed...

Comment: Just to be clear, if I type git status, it says I have 6 commits ahead of the origin/staging.  And if I type git push...nothing happens.  It just says "already up to date"...so that doesn't work.  So I am assuming I have to use what you provided?

Comment: Origin is the name of your remote repo.

Comment: yes, you have to use what I wrote, but is more organised to incorporate your commits to staging branch, let me update answer

Comment: Thank you for this! last question is there a difference between using pull --rebase versus fetch first and then merge?

Comment: yes, `pull --rebase` does `fetch` and then `rebase`, while the other thing you are mentioning is `fetch` and then `merge`, which is equivalent to `git pull` without modifiers.